# Why did Glenn Gould love the Elizabethan keyboard composers?

Tags: history, classical-music, johann-sebastian-bach

And why, after so long, have so few performers followed his lead but instead wandered after his side interest, Bach?  Were scientists the same, they'd now be spending most of their efforts on Newton's alchemy instead of his calculus.

Comment: Is it really possible to answer this question? How should we know why people long dead did what they did?

Comment: I think we need more information on how Gould preferred these composers to Bach. Did this question come from something he wrote or an interview, for example? My impression was he was a lifelong Bach fanatic, though he obviously recorded other things too.

Comment: Leibnitz , not Newton, you rotten rotten!   And Archimedes beat them both to it  https://www.sciencenews.org/article/prayer-archimedes

Comment: Gould's tastes were idiosyncratic: he liked certain of the Elizabethans/Jacobeans, but didn't cover some of the more significant keyboard composers (Bull, Farnaby) and did include (not entirely unreasonably, considering his closeness to the English) a Dutch composer (Sweelinck). However, he did produce more recordings of Schoenberg and Hindemith than any of these composers combined. Looking to Gould (to anyone, really) for confirmation of your own evaluations is perhaps a waste of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although he mentions the Elizabethans in many interviews, broadcasts, and essays, his discography turns out to include only one recording of them (CBS, S 72988). That is sufficient explanation for why others haven't continued much in his direction.